# How Do I Change My Drupal Admin Password From a Drupal Test Install on My Local Machine

Tags: users

I am a complete Drupal beginner. My Drupal site is hosted with a provider. I have these questions and would really appreciate your insight.

1) I want to be able to change the front end log in pass from cPanel in the event I get locked out. My hosting company has provided me with (a) a lengthy way to do it and (b) a short way to do it.

(a)

1. Set up up SSH access
2. From Mod Security
3. Add and whitelist my current IP address
4. Manage SSH Keys
5. Generate New Key
6. Find the Key under Public Keys section
7. Manage
8. Authorize
9. SSH Access screen
10. Manage SSH Keys again and under Private Key View/Download
11. Then "convert "id_dsa" key to PPK format"
12. Enter password and download key
13. Download/install PuTTY
14. In PuTTY go to connection, SSH, Auth and browse for coverted key file just downloaded.
15. Click Session and under Port enter 2222
16. Enter host name and Open to connect
17. Answer yes to all security prompts
18. When prompted to Login As, enter my cPanel username and for the password use the one I set for the SSH key.
19. Once connected via SSH enter "cd public_html" and go to Drupal root
20. Then enter ""php core/scripts/password-hash.sh 'NEWPASSWORD'"
21. Copy the text after where it says "hash"
22. Return to cPanel, open phpMyAdmin, click on database, look for "users_field_data table"
23. Find the account with the name "Admin"
24. Click Edit and replace the text in the pass field by pasting in the hashcode I generated.
25. Lastly, go to the table in the database named "flood" and delete any rows with my IP address.
26. Then they say "You may want to enter your IP at the top, under Filter rows.
27. Do the same for the cache_entity table.

(b) 
    Go to your cPanel -> Databases box -> phpMyAdmin.
    Select the database which Drupal uses from the drop-down menu on the left. 
    Select the right tab that says: (SQL) 
    Click the SQL tab. (I tick SQL and a text field pops up with: "Run SQL query/queries on database" (database name)
    In the SQL text field page type the following text:

**update users set pass=md5(’NEW PASS’) where uid = 1;**

Where NEWPASS is your desired new administrative password.

Then click on the GO button and if no errors present, the Drupal password should have been changed.

(a) is very difficult.

(b) is easier but I'm not confident that (b) is correct. Is it?

(c) I want to download/install a test Drupal to my local machine and try these tasks before I attempt them on my live site.

(d) Can I test these tasks on a my local machine with Drupal installed as a test version?

(e) Of the three installers at https://bit.ly/2QeuFLd which one do you suggest for a beginner?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to use Drush to set a password or get an automatic login link

Comment: Yeah, with Drush that would be [`drush uli`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:login/) to get a one time login and then change your password from there.

Comment: Thanks to Kevin and leymannx. Now I just have to understand how to use Drush.  Can I install it to my local machine and test it first with a test version of Drupal? I believe my previous support used Composer to install Drupal. Must I use one or the other or are they interchangable? I don't want to try these task on my live site. I'm certain to mess things up.

Comment: I'd recommend getting setup with a VM on your local, that way anything like drush will be baked in and you won't have to install it in your host OS. Some platforms are Docksal, Lando, and Ddev among others.

Comment: Thank you Danny.

Comment: It seems a pretty simple way to manually reset a Drupal admin pass is to reset the User pass from my phpMyAdmin database e.g. remove the password that's already there, input a new pass, then choose MD5 from the functions drop down and save it. Would you reccomend this?

Answer (score 0):

short version use "drush uli"
longer version have a local install with known password, go to your cpannel -> phpMyAdmin change the password to the known one. - done